# Dynamics of Loss in Homogeneous, Non-Smooth Models Using Clarke Subdifferential

Tags: derivatives, optimization, non-convex-optimization, non-smooth-analysis, non-smooth-optimization

**tl;dr:** Seeking insights on the application of Clarke subdifferential for analyzing the optimization differential inclusion with smooth objective and homogeneous model. I'm interested in its validity, especially considering non-standard descent directions. This question was orchestrated by GPT4.

I'm studying the dynamics of loss over time in a class of homogeneous, non-smooth models using Clarke subdifferential. This approach is interesting as it extends the gradient to include such non-smooth functions. Below are the key concepts and my question:

**Clarke Subdifferential Definition:**
The Clarke subdifferential of a function $\mathcal{L} : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ at a point $x$ is given by:
$$
  \partial^{\circ} \mathcal{L}(\theta) := \text{conv} \left \lbrace \lim_{i \to \infty} \nabla \mathcal{L}(\theta_i) : \mathcal{L} \text{ differentiable at } \theta_i  \land \lim_{i \to \infty} \theta_i \to \theta  \right \rbrace .
  $$
If $\mathcal{L}$ is continuously differentiable at $\theta$, then $\partial^{\circ} \mathcal{L}(\theta) = \lbrace \nabla \mathcal{L}(\theta) \rbrace$.

**Flow Dynamics and Differential Inclusion:**
In an optimization process modeled as a flow, the parameter trajectory $\lbrace \theta^{(t)} | t \ge 0 \rbrace$ adheres to a differential inclusion $D$ defined from $\tilde \nabla$ intended to reference some association with the gradient. So we have adherence to $D$ for almost all $t \ge 0$:
$$
  \dot \theta^{(t)} \in - D .
  $$

**Challenges with Non-Standard Descent Directions:**
The non-standard descent directions in these models complicate the analysis of loss dynamics. To approach this, I aim to bound the rate of loss decrease using the function $\alpha(t)$, defined as:
$$
  \alpha(t) := \text{max} \left \lbrace \partial^{\circ} (\mathcal{L} \circ \theta)'(t)  \right \rbrace  \\  = -\text{min} \left \lbrace \lim_{i \to \infty} \langle \nabla \mathcal{L}(\theta_i), \tilde \nabla \mathcal{L}(\theta_i) \rangle : \mathcal{L} \text{ differentiable at } \theta_i  \land \lim_{i \to \infty} \theta_i \to \theta  \right \rbrace .
  $$

**My Questions:**

1. Is this a legitimate way to bound the Clarke subdifferential? I can assume that the set over which $\nabla \mathcal{L}$ and $\tilde \nabla \mathcal{L}$ are well-defined overlap in various ways if that helps.
2. Is there any generalized minimum-norm path principle that simplifies the subdifferential to a "small" set as is the case with gradient flow?

Comment: Please do not ask questions formulated by GPT4. The definition of the subdifferential is incorrect to start with, personally I would not want to spend any more time looking.

Comment: @copper.hat please qualify your statement, you seem to have jumped to conclusions. A standard definition is being presented. See section 2.2 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07795.

Comment: It is not correct nor is it a standard definition.

Comment: @copper.hat provide your definition please. The reference I gave sources from F.H. Clarke. See the definition immediately preceding Theorem 1.5 in [1] which provides the definition as: $ \partial f(x) = \text{co} \left \lbrace \lim_{i \to \infty} \nabla f(x_i) : x_i \to x , f'(x_i) \text{ exists } \right \rbrace . $ These are equivalent notions.

Comment: [1] F.H. Clarke, Y.S. Ledyaev, R.J. Stern, and P.R. Wolenski. Nonsmooth analysis and
control theory, volume 178. Springer Science & Business Media, 2008 | https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97650

Comment: The gradients must converge. The standard definition of the beneralised gradient is the members of $(\mathbb{R}^d)^*$ majorised by $f^\circ(x ; v)$, the latter being the generalised (one sided) directional derivative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150913/discussion-between-zach466920-and-copper-hat).